# oc cluster up can't start kube-apiserver due to missing ~/.kube/config

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, openshift, openshift-client-tools, okd

I try to run OKD on my desktop (Ubuntu 18). I follow instruction: https://opensource.com/article/18/11/local-okd-cluster-linux ([similar](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-openshift-origin-on-ubuntu-18-04/)).

1. I have Docker installed:

```
$ docker version
...
 Version:           19.03.12
```

2. Insecured registry:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "172.30.0.0/16" ]
}
```

3. Restarted Docker deamon:

```
$ docker info
...
Insecure Registries:
  172.30.0.0/16
  127.0.0.0/8
```

4. Disabled firewall:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

5. Downloaded OKD client tools:

`oc` and `kubectl` from https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/download/v3.11.0/openshift-origin-client-tools-v3.11.0-0cbc58b-linux-64bit.tar.gz

```
$ ./oc version
oc v3.11.0+0cbc58b
kubernetes v1.11.0+d4cacc0
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO
```

6. I try to start cluster but it fails.

```
$ ./oc cluster up
Getting a Docker client ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11 is available ...
Creating shared mount directory on the remote host ...
Determining server IP ...
Checking if OpenShift is already running ...
Checking for supported Docker version (=>1.22) ...
Checking if insecured registry is configured properly in Docker ...
Checking if required ports are available ...
Checking if OpenShift client is configured properly ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11 is available ...
Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11 ...
I1104 16:54:53.631254    6317 config.go:40] Running "create-master-config"
I1104 16:54:56.048019    6317 config.go:46] Running "create-node-config"
I1104 16:54:57.639381    6317 flags.go:30] Running "create-kubelet-flags"
I1104 16:54:58.559780    6317 run_kubelet.go:49] Running "start-kubelet"
I1104 16:54:58.862023    6317 run_self_hosted.go:181] Waiting for the kube-apiserver to be ready ...
```

Long waiting and after that:

```
E1104 16:59:58.864017    6317 run_self_hosted.go:571] API server error: Get https://127.0.0.1:8443/healthz?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused ()
Error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

---

With higher logging level (I know that I have to remove `openshift.local.clusterup` directory or pass `--base-dir` when I want to fresh `oc cluster up`):

```
$ ./oc cluster up --loglevel=5
...
I1104 17:07:50.991364   14512 run_self_hosted.go:181] Waiting for the kube-apiserver to be ready 
I1104 17:07:50.992053   14512 run_self_hosted.go:557] Server isn't healthy yet.  Waiting a little while. Get https://127.0.0.1:8443/healthz?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused
I1104 17:07:51.992467   14512 run_self_hosted.go:557] Server isn't healthy yet.  Waiting a little while. Get https://127.0.0.1:8443/healthz?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused
I1104 17:07:52.993484   14512 run_self_hosted.go:557] Server isn't healthy yet.  Waiting a little while. Get https://127.0.0.1:8443/healthz?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused
...
I1104 17:08:10.992682   14512 run_self_hosted.go:557] Server isn't healthy yet.  Waiting a little while. Get https://127.0.0.1:8443/healthz?timeout=32s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
...
error: unable to recognize "/namespace.yaml": Get https://127.0.0.1:8443/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused
...
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:8443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
...
E1104 17:08:52.435348   14512 interface.go:34] Failed to install "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator": failed to install "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator": cannot create container using image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11; caused by: cannot create container using image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11
E1104 17:08:53.087022   14512 interface.go:34] Failed to install "kube-dns": failed to install "kube-dns": cannot create container using image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11; caused by: cannot create container using image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11
I1104 17:08:53.087047   14512 interface.go:41] Finished installing "kube-proxy" "kube-dns" "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator" "openshift-apiserver"
Error: [failed to install "kube-proxy": cannot create container using image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11; caused by: cannot create container using image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11, failed to install "openshift-apiserver": cannot create container using image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11; caused by: cannot create container using image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11, failed to install "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator": cannot create container using image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11; caused by: cannot create container using image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11, failed to install "kube-dns": cannot create container using image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11; caused by: cannot create container using image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11]
```

---

I try to check what is wrong and I notice there is issue with missing configuration.

```
$ ./oc cluster status
Error: invalid configuration: Missing or incomplete configuration info.  Please login or point to an existing, complete config file:

  1. Via the command-line flag --config
  2. Via the KUBECONFIG environment variable
  3. In your home directory as ~/.kube/config

To view or setup config directly use the 'config' command.
```

I don't have environment variable:

```
$ echo $KUBECONFIG
```

And I don't have `~/.kube/config` file:

```
$ cat ~/.kube/config
cat: /home/my-username/.kube/config: No such file or directory
$ ls ~/.kube/
ls: cannot access '/home/my-username/.kube/': No such file or directory
```

I know that `oc cluster up` should create `~/.kube/config`. **But in my case, it doesn't create.**

---

Even `kubectl` doesn't work due to missing configuration (I think it should work with typical kubectl installation from binary https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-binary-with-curl-on-linux):

```
$ ./kubectl version --client
error: no configuration has been provided
```

```
$ ./kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue.

I have Ubuntu with disabled firewall (ufw). But iptables still works.

Command `sudo iptables -L` shows me many rules which those four:

```
Chain KUBE-SERVICES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.30.237.36        /* default/router:80-tcp has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:http reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.30.1.1           /* default/docker-registry:5000-tcp has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:5000 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.30.237.36        /* default/router:443-tcp has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:https reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.30.237.36        /* default/router:1936-tcp has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:1936 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

I don't know where they come from (I can guess - below). I decited to delete it.

```
sudo iptables -L --line-numbers
sudo iptables -D KUBE-SERVICES 1
sudo iptables -D KUBE-SERVICES 1
sudo iptables -D KUBE-SERVICES 1
sudo iptables -D KUBE-SERVICES 1
```

And restart system (for sure that iptables is reloaded).

After `./oc cluster up` it starts and `~/.kube/config` is created.

```
Server Information ...
OpenShift server started.

The server is accessible via web console at:
    https://127.0.0.1:8443
```

---

I guess rules can come from `oc cluster up` when I run it once at beginning without adding  `"insecure-registries" : [ "172.30.0.0/16" ]` to `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (I tried to check if this is mandatory)

Comment: I am facing the same issue on a CentOS box. Please suggest me what to do?